# CakePHP Paginator, how to make current page an anchor

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

In my view I am using this code:

```
$numbers = $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
    'separator'     => '',
    'tag'           => 'li',
    'currentClass'  => 'active'
));
```

which outputs:

```
<li class="active">1</li>
<li><a href="/controller/action/page:2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="/controller/action/page:3">3</a></li>
```

This works pretty well, the only issue I have with it is that the current page is not a link. Is it possible to make the current page a link?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: which cersion of cakephp you are using??

Comment: try to give seperator false and try

Comment: I tried setting the seperator to false, but it produced the same result, and I am using cake 2.0.5.

Comment: FYI: the currentClass option is only available from cake 2.1 and beyond. So that wasn't actually working. I added my solution below for anyone who is having this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a class extension like Dave suggested, but instead of copying all the code from the original class, I did a string replace method instead, that way, if I update the CakePHP core library, this should fail pretty gracefully, where as copying all the code from the original Helper may cause loss of features, bug fixes, etc. Here is the class that I implemented:

```
<?php

class AppPaginatorHelper extends PaginatorHelper
{
    public function numbers($options = array()) {
        $output = parent::numbers($options);

        // get the current page number, and create a link with it
        $current = $this->current();
        $currentLink = $this->link($current, array('page' => $current));

        // if you're using cake pre 2.1 you cannot change the current class with
        // the options array, so it will always be "current"
        $find = "<li class=\"current\">{$current}</li>";
        $replace = "<li class=\"active\">{$currentLink}</li>"; 

        $output = str_replace($find, $replace, $output);

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a PR made to make it work.
Unfortunately it's just going to happen in 2.3 version.

Here you can find the PR
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/900

Here you can find the Discussion
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2892-paginator-helper-numbers-is-a-bit-counter-intuitive-enhancement-included

Answer (score 2):

You can make what you want by using the next piece of code:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','tag' => 'li', 'currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active')); ?>
```

**It only works for CakePHP 2.3+**

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:**

I don't believe it's available with the [Paginator Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html).

If you just want a link to the current page but don't need it within the numbered links, you could use

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Paginator->counter('{:current}'), 'yourLinkHere');
```

But that's not incredibly helpful, since you're relying on the Paginator Helper to take care of the rest of the links for you.

**Extended answer / possibility**

You could extend the PaginatorHelper with something like this below.  Basically, I just removed the check to see if it's the current page number.  Then you'd have to use `MyPaginatorHelper` to build the links instead.  This would also make it ignore the `currentClass` option...etc.  But - with some more tweaking of the code, you could just make it so it does the same thing but also builds a link instead of just removing the IF check.

```
class MyPaginatorHelper extends PaginatorHelper {
    public function numbers($options = array()) {
    if ($options === true) {
        $options = array(
            'before' => ' | ', 'after' => ' | ', 'first' => 'first', 'last' => 'last'
        );
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'tag' => 'span', 'before' => null, 'after' => null, 'model' => $this->defaultModel(), 'class' => null,
        'modulus' => '8', 'separator' => ' | ', 'first' => null, 'last' => null, 'ellipsis' => '...', 'currentClass' => 'current'
    );
    $options += $defaults;

    $params = (array)$this->params($options['model']) + array('page' => 1);
    unset($options['model']);

    if ($params['pageCount'] <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    extract($options);
    unset($options['tag'], $options['before'], $options['after'], $options['model'],
        $options['modulus'], $options['separator'], $options['first'], $options['last'],
        $options['ellipsis'], $options['class'], $options['currentClass']
    );

    $out = '';


        $half = intval($modulus / 2);
        $end = $params['page'] + $half;

        if ($end > $params['pageCount']) {
            $end = $params['pageCount'];
        }
        $start = $params['page'] - ($modulus - ($end - $params['page']));
        if ($start <= 1) {
            $start = 1;
            $end = $params['page'] + ($modulus - $params['page']) + 1;
        }

        if ($first && $start > 1) {
            $offset = ($start <= (int)$first) ? $start - 1 : $first;
            if ($offset < $start - 1) {
                $out .= $this->first($offset, compact('tag', 'separator', 'ellipsis', 'class'));
            } else {
                $out .= $this->first($offset, compact('tag', 'separator', 'class') + array('after' => $separator));
            }
        }

        $out .= $before;

        for ($i = $start; $i < $params['page']; $i++) {
            $out .= $this->Html->tag($tag, $this->link($i, array('page' => $i), $options), compact('class')) . $separator;
        }

        if ($class) {
            $currentClass .= ' ' . $class;
        }
        $out .= $this->Html->tag($tag, $params['page'], array('class' => $currentClass));
        if ($i != $params['pageCount']) {
            $out .= $separator;
        }

        $start = $params['page'] + 1;
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
            $out .= $this->Html->tag($tag, $this->link($i, array('page' => $i), $options), compact('class')) . $separator;
        }

        if ($end != $params['page']) {
            $out .= $this->Html->tag($tag, $this->link($i, array('page' => $end), $options), compact('class'));
        }

        $out .= $after;

        if ($last && $end < $params['pageCount']) {
            $offset = ($params['pageCount'] < $end + (int)$last) ? $params['pageCount'] - $end : $last;
            if ($offset <= $last && $params['pageCount'] - $end > $offset) {
                $out .= $this->last($offset, compact('tag', 'separator', 'ellipsis', 'class'));
            } else {
                $out .= $this->last($offset, compact('tag', 'separator', 'class') + array('before' => $separator));
            }
        }

    }

    return $out;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions about the PaginatorHelper. It seemed like such a simple option, to keep them all links, that I thought maybe the folks working on CakePHP would have added it in there. I did end up making a class that extends in the PaginatorHelper, but implemented it a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

I find a good solution and share it for you :)

```
<div class="pagination pagination-large">
    <ul>
            <?php
                echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('prev'), array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
                echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active','tag' => 'li','first' => 1));
                echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next'), array('tag' => 'li','currentClass' => 'disabled'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
            ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```